# systemdのユニットファイル中に含まれるハイフンの意味は？

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel

[systemd のユニットファイルの作成および変更 - Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/ja-JP/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html)

上記ページ中の「例9.17 postfix.service ユニットファイル」に以下のような記載があります。

```
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/network
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/postfix/aliasesdb
ExecStartPre=-/usr/libexec/postfix/chroot-update
```

先頭のハイフンが意味する事が不明です。
systemdのユニットファイルの形式でしょうか？
それともLinuxコマンドの文法的に意味を持った内容でしょうか？

Comment: [Understanding Systemd Units and Unit Files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) によると、`ExecStartPre` の場合は `they can be preceded by "-" to indicate that the failure of the command will be tolerated.` との事です。

Comment: `EnvironmentFile` については `systemd.exec(5)` に、`optionally prefixed with "-", which indicates that if the file does not exist, it will not be read and no error or warning message is logged.` と記載されています。

Comment: なるほど。"-"という内容で上手く検索できず、情報にたどり着けませんでした。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @metropolis 回答を投稿される予定はありますか？

Answer (score 3):

(コメントより)

[Understanding Systemd Units and Unit Files](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) によると、`ExecStartPre` の場合は `they can be preceded by "-" to indicate that the failure of the command will be tolerated.` との事です。

`EnvironmentFile` については `systemd.exec(5)` に、`optionally prefixed with "-", which indicates that if the file does not exist, it will not be read and no error or warning message is logged.` と記載されています。